# How do I disable anti-aliasing when scaling up an image in android?

Tags: android, image, antialiasing

So I have this 15x15 pixels image which I want to scale to something like 150x150 pixels. The problem is that when I do that, the image gets all blurry because of the anti-aliasing. What I want to achieve is the image to be pixelated instead of blurred. Here's an example:

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2bw936&s=5

Is there a way to do it directly in XML? Or do I have to do it in java?

Also I have tried both of these for an imageview and they don't work.

```
android:anti-aliasing ="false"
android:filtering ="false"
```